# HTML/CSS: Reverse responsive grid behavior in bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, when using the `.col-md-*` classes or any of its variants (lg, sm, xs) the grid will snap horizontal-to-stacked at various break points.  However, I want mine to snap **from stacked to horizontal** (see image below).

Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: do you mean possible with bootstrap classes or possible defining your own classes?

Comment: @StephenThomas possible with bootstrap classes.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306103/prevent-fluid-columns-from-breaking-to-new-line-on-iphone-screen

Comment: @Vector looks close.  But it might not work on bootstrap 3.  I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-6 box'>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
    <div class='col-xs-6 box'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo [here](http://bootply.com/100533)

Comment: This looks really close.  How can I put a clearfix on both `lg` and `md` and not on `sm` or `xs`.  One bug I noticed with this is, when the second div is on the bottom the first div content doesn't fill in the empty space.

Comment: I just added two divs.  One with `clearfix visible-md` and the other with `clearfix visible-lg` and it is not horizontal anymore. However, the first div still does not fill the content area.  It's as if the other content div is still horizontally stacked beside it.

Comment: My issue is that the first and second box are not equal in size.  The first one takes up 4 columns, and the second one takes up 8.  So when the 8 column box is below, the 4 columns don't fill up all 12 columns.  They still only fill up 4 columns, and the one below only fills up 8.

Comment: You don't need both `visible-md` and `visible-lg` since the first includes the latter. The width of the `<div>` elements is set by the `col-xs-*` class. If you want the vertically stacked layout to fill the width of the container, you'll have to add your own classes and styles.